# Running a .Net 4 console application in Windows 7 in 64bit mode when it is compiled in Mono as AnyCPU

Tags: c#, windows, mono, 64-bit, anycpu

I have made a console application in `C#` using `MonoDevelop` compiled with `Mono 3.2.1` configured as `AnyCPU` in my `Ubuntu` system.

When I take this application into some `Windows 7 64bit` system and run it, in task manager list it shows a `*32` postfix by its process name. Doesn't that mean it's run as a 32bit program? What should I do in order for this application to be run in `64bit`?

**[UPDATE]**

As a point was made in comments, let me clarify that in `Windows 7` machine I'm using Microsoft's .Net library and not Mono's.

**[UPDATE]**

I searched the Internet a little bit and found out the following command which outputs stuff about an executable file in Linux:

```
:~$ file /bin/bash 
/bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0xe643cefb2c672ad94e955067c511537ddbab48da, stripped
```

So I tested it on a `.exe` file compiled with `AnyCPU` using `Mono` and `MonoDevelop`:

```
:~$ file /ConsoleTest/bin/Release/ConsoleTest.exe
/ConsoleTest/bin/Release/ConsoleTest.exe: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows
```

Reading the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) PE stands for 32bit programs while PE+ for 64bit ones.

Taking the tests further, I used MS Visual Studio to compile a simple console programs in three modes (`AnyCPU`, `x86` and `x64`). Once compiled I took all three of them into my Ubuntu machine and tried the `file` command on them. Here are the results:

```
:~$ file /ConsoleTest-AnyCPU.exe 
/ConsoleTest-AnyCPU.exe: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows

:~$ file /ConsoleTest-x86.exe 
/ConsoleTest-x86.exe: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows

:~$ file /ConsoleTest-x64.exe 
/ConsoleTest-x64.exe: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows
```

As you can see only the `x64` one is marked as `PE+`! Then I tried running them in both Ubuntu and Windows.

In Ubuntu all three of them run! But unfortunately I've got no mean to say whether they are running in 32bit mode or 64bit!

In Windows while all three of them run (of course they do), the hated `*32` postfix is shown in process name only in `x86` compiled mode. The lack of `*32` indicates that the other two modes of `AnyCPU` and `x64` are running in 64bit.

So my question still stands: What should I do to run an `AnyCPU` compiled program using `Mono` and `MonoDevelop` in Ubuntu, as a 64bit process in Windows?

Comment: See this old question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285415/does-mono-support-64bit-windows?rq=1 It is possible that this hasn't changed since.

Comment: I don't think that the mentioned SO question applies to mine! Because in Windows I'm not using Mono but Microsoft's .Net library. Once the project's compiled, it doesn't matter which compiler's created it (theoretically speaking) due to the fact that we are talking about .Net and CIL or at least that's my belief.

Comment: Anyone knows how to run PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386, for MS Windows on Ubuntu? I got `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error` whenever I tried to run on Ubuntu 18.04.